# Non-existent local branch configured for git pull

Tags: git

When executing `git remote show origin` it lists `Local branches for 'git pull'`

[image]

When i try and delete the local `admin` branch, i get error `error: branch'admin' not found.`

I am not familiar enough with the structure/contents of the .git folder to have an idea of where the corrupt data may be, and a search for 'admin' returns nothing. Any ideas where this phantom branch is coming from?

Comment: Note that `git remote show` sometimes produces inaccurate (and sometimes incomprehensible) reports, such as in this particular case.

Comment: @torek in this instance, it was not. The `remote tracking branch` information for the local `admin` branch was still in the repositories configuration. Not sure why it was not removed when the that branch was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial search didn't include file contents. Apparently, when the `admin` local branch was deleted, it failed to remove the `remote tracking branch` data from the repositories configuration.